# Relation between Frobenius norm and trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, trace, matrix-norms

Is the following inequality true?

$$\mbox{Tr} \left( \mathrm P \, \mathrm M^T \mathrm M \right) \leq \lambda_{\max}(\mathrm P) \, \|\mathrm M\|_F^2$$

where $\mathrm P$ is a positive definite matrix with appropriate dimension. How about the following?

$$\mbox{Tr}(\mathrm A \mathrm B)\leq \|\mathrm A\|_F \|\mathrm B\|_F$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The heart of the matter is the following key fact:

> The assignment $(A,B) \mapsto \langle A,B \rangle := \operatorname{Tr}(A^T B)$ defines a Euclidean inner product on the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ of all $m \times n$ real matrices that induces the Frobenius norm $\|\cdot\|_F$ on $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, in the sense that $$\forall C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, \quad \|C\|_F = \sqrt{\langle C,C\rangle} = \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}(C^T C)}.$$

For this, of course, you need the un-normalised trace $\operatorname{Tr}(C) = \sum_{k=1}^n C_{kk}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

Once you know this and observe (by whichever definition of the Frobenius norm you prefer) that $\|C^T\|_F = \|C\|_F$ for all $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality for the inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ immediately yields your second inequality.

The first inequality is a little bit more subtle, but isn't too bad once you recall the following basic fact about traces:

> For any orthonormal basis $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have $$\forall C \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, \quad \operatorname{Tr}(C) = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle v_k,Cv_k \rangle.$$

Now, since $P$ is positive definite, let $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $P$, with $Pv_k = \lambda_k(P)v_k$ for $0 < \lambda_1(P) \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n(P) = \lambda_{\text{max}}(P)$. If you now write
$$
 \operatorname{Tr}(PM^T M) = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle v_k,P M^T M v_k \rangle = \langle P v_k,M^T M v_k\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k(P)\langle v_k, M^T M v_k \rangle
$$
in terms of this special orthonormal basis and bound each eigenvalue of $P$ from above by $\lambda_{\text{max}}(P)$, it's now easy to get the first inequality.

Comment: Is the second inequality still valid for $A$ and $B$ members of $R^{n\times m}$ and $R^{m\times q}$? inner product is defined for same matrices.

Comment: The trace is only defined for square matrices, so you'd need $A$ to be $n \times m$ and $B$ to be $m \times n$ for the left-hand side of your second inequality to even make sense, in which case, the key observation is that $\operatorname{Tr}(AB) = \langle A^T, B \rangle$ in terms of that inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ whose associated norm is the Frobenius norm.

Comment: This proof relies on the fact that $P$ is positive definite. Can we drop this assumption if we replace “largest eigenvalue” with the spectral radius?

Comment: (For motivation, we can drop this assumption if we replace $\lambda_{max}(P)$ with $\|P\|_F$; the bound then follows from Cauchy-Schwarz and the fact that the Frobenius norm is submultiplicative. But the Frobenius norm bounds the spectral radius from above, so this bound is weaker than the desired one.)

Answer (score 7):

$$\mbox{tr}(\mathrm A \mathrm B) = \left\langle \mathrm A^\top, \mathrm B \right\rangle = \langle \mbox{vec} (\mathrm A^\top), \mbox{vec} (\mathrm B) \rangle \leq \|\mbox{vec} (\mathrm A^\top)\|_2 \|\mbox{vec} (\mathrm B)\|_2 = \|\mathrm A\|_F \|\mathrm B\|_F$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $\mathrm P$ is positive definite, $\mathrm P^{\frac 12}$ exists and is symmetric. Hence,

$$\mbox{tr} (\mathrm P \mathrm M^T \mathrm M) = \mbox{tr} (\mathrm P^{\frac 12} \mathrm P^{\frac 12} \mathrm M^T \mathrm M) = \mbox{tr} (\mathrm M \mathrm P^{\frac 12} \mathrm P^{\frac 12} \mathrm M^T) = \mbox{tr} ((\mathrm P^{\frac 12} \mathrm M^T)^T (\mathrm P^{\frac 12} \mathrm M^T)) = \|\mathrm P^{\frac 12} \mathrm M^T\|_F^2$$

We [have](https://mathoverflow.net/q/59918/91764) $\|\mathrm A \mathrm B\|_F \leq \|\mathrm A\|_2 \|\mathrm B\|_F$. Thus,

$$\mbox{tr} (\mathrm P \mathrm M^T \mathrm M) = \|\mathrm P^{\frac 12} \mathrm M^T\|_F^2 \leq \|\mathrm P^{\frac 12}\|_2^2 \|\mathrm M^T\|_F^2 = \lambda_{\max} (\mathrm P) \|\mathrm M\|_F^2$$