A trace inequality of the product of two matrices
Given an arbitrary matrix $A$ and Hermitian positive definite matrix $B$, how can one prove this inequality:
$$
|\text{Tr}(AB)| \le \|A\|_2 \text{Tr}(B)
$$
where $\|A\|_2$ is the spectral norm of $A$. Under what condition(s) does the equality hold?

thanks @TedBlack, matrix B should be Hermitian and positive definite. I made an edit to the question.

This post proves a more general result, but I suspect that there is a simpler proof that applies in your case.

Have a look at the second part of the answer by @BranimirĆaćić  where he is dealing with the first inequality https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898839/relation-between-frobenius-norm-and-trace

By a change of orthonormal basis you may assume that $B$ is a positive diagonal matrix. Then
$$
|\operatorname{tr}(AB)|
=\left|\sum_ia_{ii}b_{ii}\right|
\le\sum_i|a_{ii}|b_{ii}
\le\sum_i\left(\max_i|a_{ii}|\right)b_{ii}
\le\|A\|_2\operatorname{tr}(B).
$$
Tie occurs in the triangle (i.e., the first) inequality iff all $a_{ii}$s have the same phase; tie occurs in the second inequality iff all $a_{ii}$s have the same modulus. It follows that $|\operatorname{tr}(AB)|=\|A\|_2\operatorname{tr}(B)$ iff $A$ is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix.
By a continuity argument, we also have $|\operatorname{tr}(AB)|\le\|A\|_2\operatorname{tr}(B)$ when $B$ is positive semidefinite.
More generally, let $X$ and $Y$ be two arbitrary complex matrices. Let $Y=U|Y|$ be a polar decomposition, where $U$ is unitary and $|Y|=(Y^\ast Y)^{1/2}$. Let $A=XU$ and $B=|Y|$. Then
$$
|\operatorname{tr}(XY)|
=|\operatorname{tr}(AB)|
\le\|A\|_2\operatorname{tr}(B)
=\|X\|_2\operatorname{tr}|Y|.
$$
When $Y$ is nonsingular, $B=|Y|$ is positive definite. In this case, from our previous discussion, we see that equality holds iff $A$ is a scalar multiple of $I$, i.e., iff $X=c|Y|Y^{-1}$ for some complex number $c$.

@TedBlack You are right. I wanted to simplify the problem by normalising $A$ without knowing whether this is useful or not, but forgot about it later.
